# Meaning of the task id format in Spark logs

Tags: apache-spark

I have running a heavy Spark job, and in one of the worker node I am getting log statement as follows:

```
2019-01-25 06:34:41 INFO  Executor:54 - Running task 163.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 168)
```

> I know that here `163` is the task number, but what does the other
>   decimal part `(.1)` mean?

I saw other statements are not having this `.1`, instead they have `.0` as follows:

```
2019-01-25 06:34:10 INFO  Executor:54 - Running task 151.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 151)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the [attempt number](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5264164a67df498b73facae207eda12ee133be7d/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskInfo.scala#L114):

```scala
def id: String = s"$index.$attemptNumber"
```

A number larger than 0 indicates that task has been attempted before, and has been rescheduled, likely due to failure.